# Get cookie using aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, aiohttp

I am trying to get cookies from the browser using aiohttp. From the docs and googling I have only found articles about setting cookies in aiohttp.

In flask I would get the cookies as simply as

```
cookie = request.cookies.get('name_of_cookie')
# do something with cookie
```

Is there a simple way to fetch the **cookie from browser using aiohttp**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to fetch the cookie from the browser using aiohttp?

Not sure about whether this is simple but there is a way:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def main():
    urls = [
        'http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?test=ok',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=aiohttp.CookieJar()) as s:
            async with s.get(url) as r:
                print('JSON', await r.json())
                cookies = s.cookie_jar.filter_cookies('http://httpbin.org')
                for key, cookie in cookies.items():
                    print('Key: "%s", Value: "%s"' % (cookie.key, cookie.value))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The program generates the following output:

```
JSON: {'cookies': {'test': 'ok'}}
Key: "test", Value: "ok"
```

Example adapted from https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_advanced.html#custom-cookies + https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#cookie-jar

Now if you want to do a request using a previously set cookie:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
url = 'http://example.com'

# Filtering for the cookie, saving it into a varibale
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=aiohttp.CookieJar()) as s:
cookies = s.cookie_jar.filter_cookies('http://example.com')
for key, cookie in cookies.items():
    if key == 'test':
        cookie_value = cookie.value

# Using the cookie value to do anything you want:
# e.g. sending a weird request containing the cookie in the header instead.
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic f'{cookie_value}'"}
async with s.get(url, headers=headers) as r:
    print(await r.json())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

For testing urls containing a host part made up by an IP address use `aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=aiohttp.CookieJar(unsafe=True))`, according to https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/1183#issuecomment-247788489

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the cookies are stored in request.cookies as a dict, just like in flask, so request.cookies.get('name_of_cookie') works the same.

In the [examples](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/tree/master/examples) section of the aiohttp repository there is a file, [web_cookies.py](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/examples/web_cookies.py) that shows how to retrieve, set, and delete a cookie.  Here's the section from that script that reads the cookies and returns it to the template as a preformatted string:

```
from pprint import pformat
from aiohttp import web

tmpl = '''\
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="/login">Login</a><br/>
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a><br/>
        <pre>{}</pre>
    </body>
</html>'''

async def root(request):
    resp = web.Response(content_type='text/html')
    resp.text = tmpl.format(pformat(request.cookies))
    return resp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cookie value, domain, path etc, without having to loop thru all cookies.

```py
s.cookie_jar._cookies
```

gives you all the cookies in a defaultdict with the domains as keys and their respective cookies as values. aiohttp uses [SimpleCookie](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html)

So, to get the value of a cookie

```py
s.cookie_jar._cookies.get("https://httpbin.org")["cookie_name"].value
```

for domain, path:

```py
s.cookie_jar._cookies.get("https://httpbin.org")["cookie_name"]["domain"]

s.cookie_jar._cookies.get("https://httpbin.org")["cookie_name"]["path"]
```

more info can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html